# Python 3.4 Issue with writing to a file with time.sleep()

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, sleep

I am using Python 3.4. I'm trying to figure out why the writerow() is not working if I put a sleep timer at the end it does not write the data to the Test.dat file. The code looks like this

```
import csv, time

fileName = "Test.dat"
freq = 5; 

with open(fileName, 'a') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        data = [2014, 5, 3, 5, 26, 53, 'Price', '100.00']
        a.writerow(data)
        time.sleep(freq)
```

But then if I remove the timer it writes the data in the Test.dat file

```
import csv, time

fileName = "Test.dat"
freq = 5; 

with open(fileName, 'a') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        data = [2014, 5, 3, 5, 26, 53, 'Price', '100.00']
        a.writerow(data)
```

Ans:

```
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
2014,5,3,5,26,53,Price,100.00
```

Comment: Well it's going to wait 5 seconds between each write. You'll have to be patient

Comment: Yup, it's working for me too; it's just veeery sloooooow ;-)

Comment: Ok. Darn I need to be more patient with this lol. Saturday morning rush to go out! Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

You are waiting 5 sec and the program take a long time to end write the file:

Wait one second:

```
freq = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the sentence just like `fp.flush()`.
The function of sleep will run the same thread with your other functions, thus the `file.write()` function have no chance to push its cache into your file which is in your os.
Because of it, you should call flush() by yourself.